# How should I use the uncompyle6 tool to decompile Python 3.9 version .pyc files?

Tags: reverse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdULk.png)
How should I use the uncompyle6 tool to decompile Python 3.9 version .pyc files?

"Decompiling Python 3.9 .pyc files"
F:\ni tools\pyinstxtractor-master\encrypt_file.exe_extracted>uncompyle6 encrypt_file.pyc

uncompyle6 version 3.9.1

Python bytecode version base 3.9.0 (3425)

Decompiled from: Python 3.11.4 (tags/v3.11.4:d2340ef, Jun  7 2023, 05:45:37) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

Embedded file name: encrypt_file.py

Compiled at: 1995-09-28 00:18:56

Size of source mod 2**32: 272 bytes

Unsupported Python version, 3.9.0, for decompilation

Unsupported bytecode in file encrypt_file.py

Unsupported Python version, 3.9.0, for decompilation`